# 0% code coverage on apex class

Tags: unit-test, scheduled-apex, class

Hope all is well

I have the following class  (see below), however i am unable to test my logic, as i am getting 0% code coverage.Can any one help me write a test class for the following class below.

Idea of the class is to delete mass opportunities where the created date is over 90days old.

Looking forward to your help

```
 global class batchOpp_Delete implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'Select Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
     delete scope;
     DataBase.emptyRecycleBin(scope);  
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

  }

  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
  ID BatchId = Database.executeBatch(new batchOpp_Delete(), 2000);
 }

  Public static void SchedulerMethod() {
    string con_exp= '0 0 1 * * ?';
    System.schedule('batchOpp_Delete', con_exp, new batchOpp_Delete());
  }

 }
```

Comment: HI mohith,I would of expected the class to work with out a test class. i am very new to salesforce and especially classes

Comment: All classes & triggers require a test class that provides at least 75% coverage. I recommend you look at the Apex Workbook to help you get started. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.htm. Theres also the Force.com Workbook at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/workshops_intro.htm?language=en

Comment: Please read below documents and make an attempt                      https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_best_practices.htm                                 https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods                                            http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/09/test-class-for-batch-apex-in-salesforce.html